# Push notification on tap not redirects to a specific page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am trying to redirect to a specific page , when a notification is received by the device. i have provided the following code that pushes notification and while it is tapped it is redirecting to the home page

```
 push.on('notification', function (data) {
                                console.log('push on notification');
                                console.log(data);
                                NOTIFICATION_CONSTANT = true;
                                $location.path('/menu/notification');
                                console.log(NOTIFICATION_CONSTANT);
                                if (data.additionalData && data.additionalData.additionalData !== 'NOT_SHOW') {
                                    //$rootScope.$emit('pushNotification');
                                }
```

Comment: If your using `$stateProvider`  (default for ionic) try to use `$state.go("menu.notification")` its working for me.

Comment: here is my working code `push.on('notification', function(data) {$state.go("app.orders");});`

Comment: thanks a ton.......its working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using `$stateProvider` (default for ionic) try to use `$state.go("menu.notification")`.